# How do you add the value of one integer to another?

Tags: java

I took it upon myself to make an RPG game, and already it's starting to confuse me a little.

In the fighting part of the game, I use (what is probably) a pretty bad system to register how much damage the enemy takes when you attack it.

```
int healthStatPlayer = 1;
Double damageTaken = 0.0;
Double maxHealth = (healthStatPlayer * 100.0);
Double playerHealth = (maxHealth - damageTaken);
...
Double attackDamageEnemy (attackStatEnemy * damageMultiplierEnemy);
...
{
    if (actionCommand.equals("Attack"))
    {
        System.out.println("You dealt " + attackDamage + " damage to the enemy.");
        damageTakenEnemy = (damageTakenEnemy + attackDamage);

        //The above line is where the problem is, it's wrong - both with regards to code and to mathematics - because I don't know how to make it right

        System.out.println("The enemy has " + enemyHealth + " health
 left.");
    }
}
```

I had it set up so that the current health of the enemy is its max health minus any damage taken. This meant that, to be able to alter the current health, I would have to add the value of the player's attack damage to the enemy's "damage taken."

I just want to be able to add the number value of attackDamage (in this case, 22.5) to the value of damageTakenEnemy (initially 0, since all enemies start with max health).

Comment: At some point, you need enemyHealth = enemyHealth - damageTakenEnemy.

Comment: Can you explain why you think your code is wrong? It's correctly adding two numbers as far as I can see.

Comment: You do have syntax errors *elsewhere* in the code, but I'll assume those are transcription errors.

Comment: I thought it was wrong because, mathematically speaking it should be incorrect. for example:
A = A + B. 
With regards to proper math, that would make this equation change to:
A = (A+B)+B. 
Which should change again to:
A = ((A+B)+B)+B. 
And so on.

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, it means "calculate the right-hand side and assign that value to the left hand side". It's not the mathematical `=` symbol (the equivalent to that is `==`). In any case, variables in Java are not abstract mathematical concepts - they have actual values. You could evaluate `A == A + B` in Java and Java would add the current values of `A` and `B` and compare them to the current value of `A`. If `B` happened to be `0` currently, it would return `true`. There's no algebra involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the plus operator.

So it would be `myVariable + myOtherVariable`, you can also store this in a variable like this `myStoreVar = myVar + myOtherVar`.

If you want to increment a variable with something you can do `myStoreVar += myVar`, which will just plus `myVar` to `myStoreVar`.

In your case the answer would be `damageTakenEnemy += attackDamage` which is the same as `damageTakenEnemy = damageTakenEnemy + attackDamage`. You can clearly see here which to use, the shorter one.

You also have operators like -, *, / and %.

Answer (score 1):

Your `attackDamageEnemy` variable is missing an = and you need to make sure to set the `enemyHealth` to `enemyHealth - damageTakenEnemy` otherwise the variable will never actually be affected by your damage values.